# Maven for multiple modules

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

How do I run selected modules using parent pom in Maven like I have

```
<module>APP_1</module>
<module>web_1</module>
<module>service_1</module>
<module>schema_1</module>

<module>APP_2</module>
<module>web_2</module>
<module>service_2</module>
<<module>schema_2</module>
```

sometimes as developer if I want to build first module only so how should I achieve this task in parent pom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mvn reactor:make -Dmake.folders=barBusinessLogic
```

as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-reactor-plugin/examples.html)

Comment: This somehow did not work for me. Maven reported an error stating that - "The parameters 'artifactList' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-reactor-plugin:1.0:make are missing or invalid". Is this solution for a specific Maven version? I'm using Maven 3.0.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to make a decision.

Assuming that some of your child modules depend on other child modules you have to decide if you want to:

a) build one or more modules by themselves using the last built version of the dependent modules located in your ~/.m2/repository directory.  This is super useful if you want to, say, rebuild the `web_2` module which depends on the `service_2` module, but `service_2` is currently busted and won't compile. In this case do this:

**`mvn clean install --projects module-directory-name`**

or

b) you want to build a module and have maven recursively check all dependent modules to see if they need to be rebuilt.  This is slower and safer typically.  This command is:

**`mvn reactor:make -Dmake.artifacts=com.yourgroup:module-name`**

I use both of these at different times every day.

Comment: Happy to help...do please click the green checkmark by the answer if you are happy with it.  Also feel free to upvote any/all answers you find helpful.

Comment: It is working fine with maven 2.2.1 version but not working with 3.0.3 version any suggestions

Comment: Post a new question with the command you are running and the error you are seeing and then leave a comment back here when you do.  There can be many reasons why something won't work in 3.0.3 -- all easily fixed.